# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, smart-contract-wallets

Im trying this Solidity and VueJS tutorial from [MEDIUM](https://medium.com/@james.m.kehoe/building-a-guestbook-dapp-with-vue-js-and-truffle-e0c9e3fcdeeb).

I even git cloned the github sourcecode, but I keep getting this error on the browser console:

[image]

ERROR 1:  Error initializing Drizzle.

ERROR 2:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')

1. I imported the Drizzle NPM Module using `npm install @drizzle/vue-plugin`
2. For this, I clearly have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

FOUND THE ANSWER:

You need to know how to setup the Ganache Local with your Metamask.
Add a Custom RPC Network using these settings:

```
Network Name :  Ganache Local 
New RPC URL:    HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545
Chain ID: 1337
```

Thanks to [Ivan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUEBAS5r4Og) from Moralis.